# is org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve applicable for NIO threads in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

Unable to find documentation which states that the `StuckThreadDetectionValve` is applicable to `NIO` thread pool within tomcat. If I see the thread dump, the same set of threads gets recycled from the `NIO` pool, leaving the cpu elapsed time very high.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Stuck_Thread_Detection_Valve

set the value in embedded tomcat